# EntityFramework Insert into Oracle table with a sequence as PK

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, entity-framework

I'm doing an insert with EF like this:

```
        using (Entities1 ctx = new Entities1())
        {
            ADDRESS_RESOLVER addrRes = new ADDRESS_RESOLVER();
            addrRes.ZIP_VEGA = addr.ZipVega;

            ctx.ADDRESS_RESOLVER.Add(addrRes);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The table ADDRESS_RESOLVER has a primary key ID with a sequence associated. The trigger look like this:

```
create or replace 
trigger SEQ_ADDRESS_RESOLVER_ID  
   before insert on "MY_DB"."ADDRESS_RESOLVER" 
   for each row 
begin  
   if inserting then 
      if :NEW."ID" is null then 
         select SEQ_ADDRESS_RESOLVER.nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual; 
      end if; 
   end if; 
end;
```

The problem is my EF object addrRes has the ID settet do 0 and I cannot set it to null because it's a PK so when I try to do the insert the trigger doesn't work. My solution is changing the "if" in the trigger to "0" instead of "null" but I'm not sure if it is the right solution. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: how about a catch all - `if NVL(:NEW."ID", 0) = 0`

Comment: Yes, change the trigger to look for zero instead of NULL.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: So the real question is: "Why the hell Oracle SQL Developer automatically create a trigger for a PK that check for null if a PK cannot be null?!"

Comment: @Federico the trigger looks at the data in a kind of staging table before the final insert into the target table - and a standard insert statement would not pass a value for `id`, and it would therefore be `null` and the trigger would work as expected. The actual  problem you are facing is that EF *is* sending a value.

Comment: @Federico what DatabaseGeneratedOption are you using in the `Map` file (if you have a map file!)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by @qujck I needed to change the trigger like this:

```
    create or replace 
trigger SEQ_ADDRESS_RESOLVER_ID  
   before insert on "MY_DB"."ADDRESS_RESOLVER" 
   for each row 
begin  
   if inserting then 
      if NVL(:NEW."ID", 0) = 0 then 
         select SEQ_ADDRESS_RESOLVER.nextval into :NEW."ID" from dual; 
      end if; 
   end if; 
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change the property [StoreGeneratedPattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.storegeneratedpattern(v=vs.110).aspx) of your entities PK to "Identity" (A value is generated on insert and remains unchanged on update.)

With this solution you don't have to touch your database trigger and add the extra if statement.